# How do I get date, month, year values from a calendar javascript - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calender and when i pick a date i would like from a javascript to make a check through some values that i had choose to tell me if is it true or not.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<title>SOMETHING</title>
    <script>
function check(){ 
                 if (document.getElementById("cinema").value == "1"){
                        var d = new date();
                        var x = document.getElementById("date");
                        x.innerHTML=d.getMonth();
                        if (x == "1"){
                        document.write("ok");
                        }
                        }
                        else {
                        alert('null');
                        }
                        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
    </header>
<br />
<div>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
                <label for="date">CHECK DATE</label>
                <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required="required"/>
        <br />
                <label for="time">CHECK TIME</label>
                <input type="time" id="time" name="time" required="required" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<br />
<button onclick='check()'>Check</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to post your Javascript.  The people here will help you but not write code for you.

Comment: sorry Steve it was my fault i missed that....

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: do nothing...  also i can't understand the difference of doing this : var fordate = document.getElementByID("date").value;
alert('fordate');
} than this:
var d = new date(document.getElementById("date"));
alert(d.getMonth());

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a value to the date object first, then derive the day, month year from that.

```
var d = new date(document.getElementById("date"));
alert(d.getMonth())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should get you on the right track:

```
    function check()
    {
        var Temp= document.getElementById("date");

        var myDate = new Date(Temp.value);

        document.write(myDate);
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(myDate.getMonth()); 
    }
```

Comment: myDate.getFullYear() returns me 2013      myDate.getDate() returns me the day  but myDate.getMonth() returns 0... but as you said i am on track now! thanks! now the problem is how to compare this with a date tha i had saved once...

Answer (score 0):

that's it !

```js
function check() {
  var a = document.getElementById("thedate").value;
  var check = "2013-01-20";
  if (a == check) {
    alert("YES");
  } else {
    alert("STOP");
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<body>
  <input type="date" id="thedate">
  <button onclick="check()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What if the user enters 1/20/2013?